# How to: Connecting a Instance (Virtual Machine from Google Cloud Service) with local runtime from Google Colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, connection, virtual-machine, instance, google-colaboratory

I just struggled for 3 days to get this to work but many of the sources that explain it are somehow misleading. Therefore I share that now.
I was using windows and used the Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux to operate from there:
(instruction on how to activate you can find here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

- I first created a virtual machine on google cloud called colav-vm in the geographic zone us-east4-c
- Start the VM in google cloud
- Opened Ubuntu Linux Terminal:
- Type: 
  `gcloud compute ssh colav-vm --zone=us-east4-c -- -L 8888:locahost:8888`
- Enter Password to connect to it
- Install pip: 
   (found it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/672808/sudo-apt-get-install-python-pip-is-failing)

(**In the connected terminal from the VM**)

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

- Install jupyter_http_over_ws

```
sudo -i pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
```

- Run the jupyter-server still **on the connected VM**:

`jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws`

jupyter notebook \

--NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \

--port=8888 \

--NotebookApp.port_retries=0

(this should be also a code cell - but the formatting doesn't let me)

- Then go to the browser on your local computer and type in " http://localhost:8888/ " to open a Jupyter environment if you have it installed - or go to google Colab and connect to runtime on the top right and type it in there and connect (there you need to add the full line including the token like that:
  http://localhost:8888/?token=bd391421b3ec5c08f35ef28e2eb9d01fab6501e341c82e35)

I hope this saves some people some time.

The original sources are from here:
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html
https://medium.com/@yufengg/how-to-upgrade-colab-with-more-compute-64d53a9b05dc
(but somehow it confused me and it didn't work for me at least)

Comment: Important!!! 
after connecting with: gcloud compute ssh colav-vm --zone=us-east4-c -- -L 8888:locahost:8888
go to the browser type in: locahost:8888
then continue with launching the jupyter notebook in the terminal as explained. After that just refresh the page: locahost:8888 - and you will connect to VM Jupyter notebook

Comment: Is there have any error message when you are trying to connect? What is name of the browser you are trying?

Comment: this is now how I succeeded in connecting it - I just wanted to share that because I spent a lot of time trying to make it work.
I was using google chrome